# Django: return list/tuple of element.id and min(element.price) from chunks of queryset

Tags: python, django

I've a `cart_detail` view that will be used to offer `3x2` discounts.

So I'm making `chunks` of 3 elements from every element in my `queryset`.

**Using:**

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
```

**Queryset and Chunks generated:**

```
pack_items = PackItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)
pack_items_grouped_by_3 = chunks(pack_items, 3)
```

> Now, from every chunk I need to return a list or tuple with the min
>   price of all 3 elements and the ID of the element with the `min` price.

**I can return the min price of every chunk, but how to return also the ID of the pack from that chunk that has the min price?**

```
for e in pack_items_grouped_by_3:
    product_with_min_price = min(pack.pack.price for pack in e)
    #product_id = e.index(min(pack.pack.price for pack in e))
    #print(product_id)
```

Error: In the for loop above I've tried:

```
product_id = e.index(min(pack.pack.price for pack in e))
print(product_id)
```

**But Erro says:**

```
ValueError at /carrito_de_compras/
10 is not in list
```

10 is the min value for every chunk, in this case, maybe in the future 2 items can have price of 10 and one price of 8, and 8 would be the min price.

Comment: Can you sort the whole query result? Then it would be easier to get the min element in the chunk (obviously the first)

Comment: @Dos interesting logic, how to sort a queryset by `price` in this case?

Comment: You can just sort the queryset before chunking: pack_items = PackItem.objects.filter(cart=cart).order_by('pack__price')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) takes a key function, so one way to do this is just

```
product_with_min_price = min(e, key=lambda pack: pack.pack.price)
```

On a tangential note, I'd profile your chunker on the queryset - Django querysets implement slicing with database-level OFFSET and LIMIT operations, so it's probably going to issue a new db query for each chunk. Here, you'll probably benefit from evaluating the queryset as a list before chunking.

Comment: Works, it returns whe object with the min price, so I can access its price with: `product_with_min_price.price`. 

Would you expand on how would you profile the chunker on the queryset? Or any link on this topic.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated for the basics - to confirm my theory about multiple queries you could make sure you're running in debug mode and then check the connection object as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running - or in the past I've used a third party debug toolbar, eg https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you plan to use the chunks, it may make sense to always sort them based on price.  Then you can just take the first item.

Comment: I was just thinking this. But still need a way to pull min price and the elements id.